# How to push a screen and keep the previous one visible?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to push a `MaterialPageRoute` using `Navigator.of(context).push(...);`. The widget being pushed is just a `Scaffold` with a transparent color as its `backgroundColor`. However, when the screen is pushed, the transparent color is ignored and the previous screen remains invisible. How can this be fixed?

By the way, the only reason I am using `Navigator.of(context).push(...);` instead of `showDialog(...);` is because of bias towards the transition effect when pushing using `Navigator.of(context).push(...);`

Comment: Are you trying to push a widget but making it transparent?

Comment: @Codefarmer Yes, I am pushing a scaffold with a transparent background color.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to push a transparent route.

Option 1

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false,
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) => const Scaffold(),
      ),
    );
```

Option 2

- Create a Transparent route that extends PageRoute

```
    class TransparentRoute extends PageRoute<void> {
      TransparentRoute({
        required this.builder,
        RouteSettings? settings,
      }) : super(settings: settings, fullscreenDialog: false);
    
      final WidgetBuilder builder;
    
      @override
      bool get opaque => false;
    
      @override
      Color? get barrierColor => null;
    
      @override
      String? get barrierLabel => null;
    
      @override
      bool get maintainState => true;
    
      @override
      Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 350);
    
      @override
      Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
        final result = builder(context);
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(animation),
          child: Semantics(
            scopesRoute: true,
            explicitChildNodes: true,
            child: result,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

- Instead of MaterialPageRoute, do a TransitionRoute

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
                TransparentRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color(0XFF141010).withOpacity(0.5)
      ),
   ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `PageRouteBuilder` instead of `MaterialPageRoute`:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => NextScreen(),
  ),
);
```

It also supports transitions.